# Finding angles of right triangle without inverse trig

Tags: trigonometry

I am working through "Basic Mathematics" by Serge Lang, and there is an example in the polar coordinates section that seems incomplete to me.

> **Example.** Find polar coordinates for the point whose rectangular coordinates are $(1,\sqrt {3})$.

Their solution is

> We have $x = 1$ and $y = \sqrt{3}$, so that
>
> $$r = \sqrt{1+3} = 2$$
>   Also
>   $$cos \theta = \frac{1}{2}$$
>   and
>   $$sin \theta = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
>   We see that $\theta = \pi /3 $

At this point in the book, inverse sine and cosine have not been introduced. Was $\theta = \pi /3$ just an observation, or is there a method to determine the angles of a right triangle just using the side measurements without the inverse trig functions?

Comment: Why to use complicated advanced methods when simple observations works ?

Comment: There are tables available, where you can read the angle if you know the $\sin$, $\cos$, or $\tan$ value of that angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. More simply, $\theta=\pi/3$ or $\theta=\pi/4$ or $\theta=\pi/6$ are values for which $\sin$ and $\cos$ are mnemonical remembered. Obiuosvly, all the values of $\sin$ and $\cos$ are real so there are expression for every value of $\theta$. The expression can be very complicated or even not known.